# Accessing multiple captures in a RegEx (Newbie thing...)

Tags: javascript, regex, capture

in this regex multiple capture I have to add "g" flag to obtain all items...

"aaa bbb ccc \n.000.\n \n.111.\n sd555 dsf \n.222.\n ddd ".match( /^.(.*).$/gm )

when I add the "g" (global) flag ?how do access the captured groups... there should be 3 like ["000", "111", "222"] but i don't know how to access them... I keep getting [".000.", ".111.", ".222."] << note the dots before and after the words

Comment: which is the question?
you need 3 numbers or 3 letters or something else from the string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to get capture groups in a global regex, you can't use `match`, unfortunately.  Instead you'll need to use [`exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) on the regex:

```
var myregex = /^.(.*).$/gm;
var result, allMatches = [];
while((result = myregex.exec(mystring)) != null) {
    var match = result[1]; // get the first match pattern of this match
    allMatches.push(match);
}
```

With a global regex, `match` returns an array of all the whole matches and never returns capture groups.  `exec` returns a single match and all of its capture groups.  To get all the matches, you must call `exec` multiple times until it finally returns `null`.

**Note** that `exec` relies on the regex maintaining state, so you **must** save the regex in a variable:

```
while((result = /^.(.*).$/gm.exec(mystring)) != null) // BAD and WRONG!
```

This is wrong because with each loop, there is a fresh regex which doesn't know what match it is supposed to be returning this loop.  (Or, more precisely, it doesn't know the `lastIndex` of the previous regex.)

Answer (score 0):

The returned result from str.match( re ) is an array.

Demo here. http://jsfiddle.net/rXgQa/

```
var re = /^.(.*).$/gm;
var str = "aaa bbb ccc \n.000.\n \n.111.\n sd555 dsf \n.222.\n ddd ";
var matches = str.match( re );
if( matches ){
    document.body.innerHTML += matches.join( '<br/> ' );
}​
```

Outputs:

```
aaa bbb ccc // matches[0]
.000.     // matches[1]
.111.     // matches[2]
sd555 dsf // matches[3]
.222.     // matches[4]
ddd       // matches[5]
```

### Update

Here's my answer to the second part of the question.
Question:
How to get rid of the dot before and after the numbers?

My Answer: 
I would just loop through the matches and replace the dot with an empty string.
Also, your regular expression is wrong since you need to escape the dot.

***Updated*** jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rXgQa/1/

```
var re = /^\.([^\.]+)\.$/gm;
var lines = "aaa bbb ccc \n.000.\n \n.111.\n sd555 dsf \n.222.\n ddd ";
var matches = lines.match( re );
var i = (matches||[]).length;
while( i-- ){
    matches[i] = matches[i].replace( /\./g, '' );
}

document.body.innerHTML += matches.join( '<br/>' );
```

Comment: Ok larry, but note... the capture done by the (.*) in the regex expression should have stripped down the dots... and I should be getting ["000", "111", "222"] and not [".000.", ".111.", ".222."]

Comment: Ok... my hope to do it at once vanish... I'll stick to remove the dots after... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In FireBug:

```
var hello = "aaa bbb ccc \n.000.\n \n.111.\n sd555 dsf \n.222.\n ddd ".match( /^.(.*).$/gm );
console.dir(hello);
```

Then you can use `hello[n]` where n is the match you want, such as `hello[1].

However, you need to modify your regex if you *only* want to match certain things.

Comment: I know that, the question was how to get the capture done by the (.*) in the regex expression