# Regex - Javascript capture area

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to capture only a area of the Match part. I have following String:
`" type1-class1 type1-class2 type2-class4 type2-type1-class3 "`
and i want following result `["class1", "class2"]`.
I am searching the class by the `type`.
I have tried following:

```js
console.log(" type1-class1 type1-class2 type2-class4 type2-type1-class3 ".match(/\btype1-.*?(?= )/g))
// Result: ["type1-class1", "type1-class2", "type1-class3"]
```

Furthermore i have tried following:

```js
console.log(" type1-class1 type1-class2 type2-class4 type2-type1-class3 ".match(/(?= type1-).*?(?= )/g));
// Result: ["", ""]
```

How can i disable the capture on the beginning of a Regex?

Comment: What do you mean by `disable the capture on the beginning of a Regex`?

Comment: Do you *have* to use `String#match` rather than an `exec` loop?

Comment: Because i can use (?= ...) to match but not capture, this is only working on the center/end of a match but not at the beginning. However, i want to match a string and only to get a part of it. As i mentioned above i want to match  `" type1-class1 "` and get `"class1"` and the same on `" type1-class2 "` and get `"class2"`.

Comment: match doesn't work the way you want it to with /g and multiple matches, You will have to use http://stackoverflow.com/a/10939979/3355076

Comment: .match( /(^|[^\\])\((?!\?)/,"(?:"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use an `exec` loop. The regular expression is `/(?:^|\s)type1-([^ ]+)/g`, e.g., "Following a `type-1` that's at the beginning of the string or just after whitespace, capture everything until the next whitespace or end of string. (With your string as given, we don't need the alternation with `^`, but I wanted to allow for `"type1-class1"` at beginning of string.) We then collect the captures in a loop:

```js
var rex = /(?:^|\s)type1-([^ ]+)/g;
var str = " type1-class1 type1-class2 type2-class4 type2-type1-class3 ";
var classes = [];
var m;
while ((m = rex.exec(str)) != null) {
  classes.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(classes);
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are expecting?

```
console.log(" type1-class1 type1-class2 type2-class4 type2-type1-class3 ".match(/ type1-.*?(?= )/g).map(x=>x.replace(/type1-/g,"").trim()))
```

Comment: Answers shouldn't be questions. Also, say *what* you changed, and *why*.

Comment: *"is this what you are expecting?"* Clearly not, as the OP clearly says he/she wants `["class1", "class2"]` but the above returns `["class1", "class2", "class3"]`

Comment: But the idea of post-processing with `map` isn't a bad one, might be worth fleshing it out to make this a useful answer.

Comment: Thanks T.JCrowder for your comments. Edited this answer itself. I hope this answers AntiMuffin's query.